# When and how to fetch data for detail view in react/router/redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Say I have built a backend API for `/accounts` and `/accounts/:id` and my React app has an `AccountList` component fetching the accounts on mount. This stores the list in redux store. So far so good.
When I now navigate to `/accounts/1` I have 3 options where I would like to know the best way to design the architecture.

1. Link to `/accounts/1` calls `<AccountDetail ...>` with all the attributes for the specific account and `AccountDetail` just shows it. No additional request required, but a browser reload or direct link to `/accounts/1` will fail because no props are set.
2. Link to `/accounts/1` sets property `id` only and the `AccountDetail` component fetches the content from the backend via API. Data will always be there but it looks like a superfluous call is being triggered when I come via the Link from the list (where account data has already been loaded for all accounts).
3. Link to `/accounts/1` from the list sets all properties (which are missing when called directly via browser) but only `id` is required. `AccountDetail` would check if only `id` is provided and fetch, otherwise taking the data from the props. This adds complex logic and feels strange.
4. Link to `/accounts/1` sets property `id` only and the `AccountDetail` component fetches the content from the backend via API if the respective account is not in the react store, otherwise it gets the data from there. This combines both benefits from 1. and 2. but adds quite complex logic to the component since (I guess) I can't just check this inside `mapStateToProps` because I need to trigger an async API call.

My current `App.js`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <main role='main'>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/accounts' component={AccountOverview} />
            <Route path='/accounts/:id' render={({match}) => (<AccountDetail id={parseInt(match.params.id, 10)} />)} />
          </main>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

`nav_bar.js` contains

```
<Menu.Item key={i} as={NavLink} to={item.to}>{item.text}</Menu.Item>
```

which is basically a `<NavLink to='/accounts'>Accounts</NavLink>` using semantic-ui.

And the `AccountsList` renders a

```
<Link to={'/accounts/' + id}>{service}</Link>
```

Hope it was clear enough.
How are you dealing with this? What's the "common" or "best" approach to deal with list and detail?

Comment: Hi! could you add your router setup?

Comment: @soupette: updated my post. Hope it's enough and what you asked for :)

Comment: Well if you want to limit the number of requests you can simply fetch your accounts in your `App` container and use selectors in both `AccountOverview` and `AccountDetail`. This way you get rid of the page reload issue and don't have to refetch data when you navigate back and forth to `/accounts`

Comment: @soupette there will be more besides accounts. Wouldn't this mean to load all the data in the app container? Especially for deep link, each entity would be loaded even if I want to call an account or something else?

Comment: You're right but it's the only way I can think of if you want to limit the number of requests. Maybe you can try to have a selector in your AccountDetail container that get the state of AccountOverview and if it undefined you make your request to get the data. But I'm not sure this will work

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm quite new with react/redux it still looks weird to me. Something like "not thought through". I'll play around with your suggestion while continuing to look around for some hints or best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and had some trouble fixing it. The way that worked for me i did a detail view example "accounts/:id" and in that component on componentDidUpdate() or componentDidMount() called an api via axios and got the payload in the props using redux.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSingleEmail(this.props.match.params.id);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
        this.props.getSingleEmail(this.props.match.params.id);
    }
}
```

I figured you need both mount and update in case you access other ids so the componentDidMount will not trigger, and in the case of first load componentDidUpdate will not trigger.

Comment: likely better to switch over to useEffect at this point given where React is headed